# I need to get more than 100 pages in my query

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to get all video information posible from Youtube for my proyect. I know that the limit page is 100.

I do the next code:

```
         ArrayList<String> videos  = new ArrayList<>();
         int i = 1;
         String peticion = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=Comedy&alt=json&max-results=50&page=" + i;
         URL oracle = new URL(peticion);
             URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                         yc.getInputStream()));
             String inputLine = in.readLine();
             while (in.readLine() != null) 
             {
                 inputLine = inputLine + in.readLine();
             }

             System.out.println(inputLine);

             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(inputLine);
             JSONObject jsonFeed = jsonObj.getJSONObject("feed");
             JSONArray jsonArr = jsonFeed.getJSONArray("entry");

             while(i<=100)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < jsonArr.length(); j++) {
                     videos.add(jsonArr.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("id").getString("$t"));
                     System.out.println("Numero " + videosTotales + jsonArr.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("id").getString("$t"));
                     videosTotales++;
                 }
                 i++;
             }
```

When the program finish, I have 5000 videos per category, but I need much more, much much more, but the limit is page = 100.

So, how can I get more than 10 millions of videos?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are those 5000 also unique id's ?
I see the use of max-results=50, but not a start-index parameter in your url.
There is a limit on the results you can get per request. There is also a limit on the number of requests that you can send within some time interval. By checking the statuscode of the response and any error message you can find these limits, as they may change in time.

Besides the category parameter, use some other parameters too. For instance, you may vary the q parameter (used with some keywords) and/or order parameter to get a different results set.
See the documentation for available parameters.

Note, that you are using api version 2, which is deprecated. There is an api version 3.